# Dispersion of finite 2D lattice

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, lattice-model, dispersion, coupled-oscillators

Following problem: I have the coupling matrix for an $N$-by-$N$ finite lattice of coupled masses (only nearest-neighbour coupling, periodic until terminated). I would like to numerically calculate its band structure.

Because it is 2D, I have the matrix as a pentadiagonal $N^2 \times N^2$ matrix (as opposed to tridiagonal for the 1D).

Diagonalizing it is straightforward but how do I actually assign a momentum to each of the eigenvalues I get out? Do I need to look at every single eigenmode individually or is there a way to assure that the diagonalized coupling matrix comes out in some predictably sorted way that allows me to know which eigenvalue belongs to which momentum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your $N\times N$ lattice has periodic boundary conditions and you have translation symmetry. If so, you have two translation operators $T_x$ and $T_y$ that commute with your matrix $H$ (and each other) and thus have common eigenvectors. The eigenvectors of the translation operator are labeled by momenta $k$.

In particular $T_x^N=1$, and you therefore have eigenvalues $e^{\frac{2\pi i}N k_x}$ where $k_x=0,\dots, N-1$. Similarly for $T_y$. If you have an eigenvector of $H$
$$ Hv_\lambda = \lambda v_\lambda$$
with no degeneracy, then you can measure the momenta as follows
$$ T_xv_\lambda = e^{\frac{2\pi i}N k_x}v_\lambda \qquad T_yv_\lambda = e^{\frac{2\pi i}N k_y}v_\lambda.$$
This eigenvector $v_\lambda$ has momenta $(k_x, k_y)$. If you have a degeneracy, ie several eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$: $$v^{(1)}_\lambda, \dots, v^{(r)}_\lambda$$
then these $H$ eigenvectors are not necessarily eigenvectors of $T_x$ and $T_y$. In order to momentum-resolve these, you need to find the correct superposition of these. A straightforward, although probably not the most numerically efficient, way to do this is to construct projection operators.
For example something like
$$ P_x(k_x) = \frac 1N\sum_{n=1}^N e^{-\frac{2\pi i}N k_x n} T_x^n. $$
If I wrote it correctly, this should satisfy $P_x(k_x)^2=P_x(k_x)$ and be Hermitian (thus is a projection). Furthermore you have something like
$$ T_xP_x(k_x) = e^{\frac{2\pi i}N k_x}P_x(k_x).$$
This means that for any vector $v$, $P(k_x)v$ is either zero or an eigenstate of $T_x$ with eigenvalue $^{\frac{2\pi i}N k_x}$.
You have a similar projector for $T_y$. You can thus momentum-resolve a degenerate set of vectors $v^{(1)}_\lambda, \dots, v^{(r)}_\lambda$, by acting with $P_x(k_x)$ and $P_y(k_y)$ on these vectors until you find $r$ linearly independent vectors. These will all have well-defined momentum.

An easier and numerically more efficient way to do this might be the following. Instead of diagonalizing $H$, you should instead diagonalize
$$ H' = H + \delta_x T_x + \delta_y T_y,$$
for some very small numbers $\delta_x$ and $\delta_y$. This will make it more likely that the computer spits out momentum resolved eigenvectors, and you can thus avoid projectors on degenerate state.

Comment: It does not have periodic boundary conditions. The lattice itself is periodic (until terminated), though.

Comment: @nsnfn Maybe I am misunderstanding the context, but I don't think you have a well-defined momentum to assign to eigenstates if you don't have translation symmetry. Which you don't have with open boundary conditions (terminated lattice). Band structures of electronic and phononic systems are based on translation symmetry.